# How to get auto incremented field

Tags: php, mysql

How to get the auto incremented field after inserting to the database example. If a complaint is registered and the complaint id should be shown to the user.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (cardno, comp, firno, compdate) VALUES ('$CardNo', '$Reason', '$Fir',CURDATE())";
mysql_query($sql);
```

I tried this but its showing only the 1st inserted record.

Comment: One possible downside to using the auto-increment ID publicly is that by filing 2 complaints over a period of time, people can see how many complaints your site gets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysql_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) returns the autoincrement id from the last query

But forget mysql, move into the 20th century and use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (or even into the 21st century and use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php))

Comment: +1 but it would be worth mentioning that you would use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php.

Comment: I wouldn't say that PDO is that modern. Personally I would prefer mysqli to build some abstraction library.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: I wrote a lot of the code for Zend Framework's DB component, which supports both mysqli and PDO.  Having that experience, I greatly prefer PDO.

Comment: May I ask for some examples? mysqli is a honest raw API while PDO is a wannabe-abstraction library, with very limited features and obscure internals. The only fact that it was vulnerable to infamous GBK encoding injection up to version 5.3 is significant for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth mentioning that `mysql_insert_id()` (for mysql extension) and [$mysqli->insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php) (for mysqli) are the wrappers for native MySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID`. So you can also use it in this way:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); // select last generated auto increment id
```